# Polymer 1.0 skip nodes with ExcludeLocalNames

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I try to migrate from Polymer 0.5 to 1.0 and got the following question:

Does anybody know, how to ignore nodes inside a `paper-menu`? In 0.5 you could set the attribute `excludedLocalNames` to ignore some of them, but in 1.0 it seems to have changed.

In the IronSelectableBehavior, there is still the property `excludedLocalNames`, so i thought it must be still working. Has anybody a working example?

The following code was my first attemp to create a submenu with that feature, but the submenu is not ignored by the parent:

```
<paper-menu selected="{{route}}" attr-For-Selected="entry" excludedLocalNames="paper-menu">
    <paper-icon-item entry="home">
        <iron-icon icon="home" item-icon></iron-icon>
        Übersicht
    </paper-icon-item>
    <paper-icon-item entry="page1">
        <iron-icon icon="label" item-icon></iron-icon>
        Page1
    </paper-icon-item>
    <template is="dom-if" if="{{computeEquals(route,'page1')}}">
        <paper-menu class="submenu" selected="{{routePage1}}" attr-For-Selected="entry1">
            <paper-icon-item entry1="basics">
                <iron-icon icon="icons:assignment" item-icon></iron-icon>
                Basics
            </paper-icon-item>      
            <paper-icon-item entry1="tools">
                <iron-icon icon="icons:apps" item-icon></iron-icon>
                Tools
            </paper-icon-item>  
        </paper-menu>   
    </template>
    <paper-icon-item entry="page2">
        <iron-icon icon="label" item-icon></iron-icon>
        Page2
    </paper-icon-item>      
</paper-menu>
```

Because there is no more submenu-element in 1.0, I tried that way to put a menu inside of a menu. But if I click on a submenu-item, the parent-menu changes his focused item...

Has anybody an idea how to use the `excludeLocalNames`-attribute?

**Edit**

Here are links to the documentations:

- [IronSelectableBehavior](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-selector?active=Polymer.IronSelectableBehavior)
- [paper-menu](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-menu)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `excludedLocalNames` in 1.0. Instead, set the `selectable` property on the selector to the names of the nodes you would like to allow selection for. Basically, it's a whitelist instead of a blacklist (which is a lot more reliable, too).

For example:

```html
<paper-menu selectable="paper-item,div">

  <paper-item>You can select me!</paper-item>

  <div class="menu-item">You can select me, too.</div>

  <paper-icon-item icon="user">You can't select me.</paper-icon-item>

  <header>I'm not selectable either.</header>

</paper-menu>
```

Comment: I love that it's a full CSS/querySelector selector, you could even use `selectable="[selectable]"` and set a `selectable` attribute on anything you want to be able to select.

Comment: Pretty sure `excludedLocalNames` should still work, however when using it as an html attribute, you need to lower case and separate with "-": `excluded-local-names"

Comment: @ebidel I remember trying it as an attribute and the only way I could get it to work was by programmatically setting it like: `paperMenu.excludedLocalNames['a'] = 1;` - however that suffered from [a bug](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-selector/issues/14) that would make all the selectors inherit that behavior (which I noticed you've left a comment on). All this being said, though, last I tried was around the time I made the bug report. Anything change in that time?

Comment: Ah that was you! Yea, there seems to be a few bugs with iron-selector that we need to work out. Ran into a bunch after porting an app the last couple of days.

Comment: @ebidel I was just perusing through `iron-selector` actually (submitted a PR to fix some other functionality) and noticed that `excludedLocalNames` [isn't even defined as a public property](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-selector/blob/master/iron-selectable.html#L107). That would certainly explain why it doesn't work as an attribute. I do remember speaking with Scott and he said I should avoid it, that it's not really meant to be touched, or something along those lines - that's why I ultimately said "don't use it" in my answer. But as long as it's there...

Comment: `excludedLocalNames` should be private (that is, `_excludedLocalNames`). It's a bug that it's not.